# SSRS 2008 Tablix containing subreports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with a Tablix.  The purpose of this report is to output an Excel friendly report so that users can work and manipulate columns and cells and sort on data.  My Tablix contains 2 subreports.  One of the subreports may return multiple rows and when it does, it causes data in my Tablix to merge multiple rows on Excel output.

Note:  The subreports are needed because the data lies at to different geographical locations, so webservices are used to return external data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do some additional work to make sure that multiple rows were not returned and limit the return data to 1 row.